# Including Extra Debuging Info in Source File for debugging using gdb in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, metadata, codeblocks

When debugging C++ source in Code::Blocks, points passed a function parameter or a members of data structures are just displayed as their address.

After some research I found I can enter the a custom watch as <pointer-name>@<numerical-size of variable-containing-size> to get it to display as an array, however I can't edit the default display on the structure.

I was wondering if there is some way to mark up the source code with special comments that can be parsed during debug to automate this and make complex object easier to view during debugging.

i.e.

```
struct {
    size_t n;
    int *p; /* I want gdb to interpreted this symbols as p@n by default */
}
```

I would also like to be able to make similar specification for function parameters.

First is this even possible, I can't find any thing online about marking up the source for helping gdb, and suspect it never even looks at the source since the debugging information is either stored in the executable or a debug database.

If there is some way of doing this, how would I do it?

Note: if there is a Code::Blocks specific solution, I would be happy with that.

Comment: You can write a python pretty printer for this kind of inspections.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you have seems not to be related to quality of debug information but merely how debugger displays values of variables of certain type. That is usually configurable or scriptable.

Code::Blocks uses squirrel script for [Debugger scripting](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Debugger_scripts). By extending that script you can make debugger to command GDB in specific manner and then to parse and display the outcome how you like. That gdb_types.script in scripts folder is ran by Code::Blocks.

If you want to [script GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Extending-GDB.html#Extending-GDB) itself then that can be done in "Settings -> Compiler & Debugger -> Debugger -> Initial commands" of Code::Blocks, provided script will be ran by GDB. Then you can call the functions defined in that script from the gdb_types.script.

Comment: This looks like it would do what I want, However I can't see how to add the script to my project. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Just modify the gdb_types.script file in scripts folder and then use "Settings -> Compiler & Debugger -> Debugger -> show debugger pane" to see how it works.